# Extract specific data from full mysqldump backup

Tags: backup, mysql

I am making regular backups of my `MySQL` database with mysqldump. This gives me a .sql file with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, allowing me to restore my database on demand. However, I have yet to find a good way to extract specific data from this backup, e.g. extract all rows from a certain table matching certain conditions.

Thus, my current approach is to restore the entire file into a new temporary database, extract the data I actually want with a new `mysqldump` call, delete the temporary database and then import the extracted lines into my real database.

Is this really the best way to do this? Is there some sort of script that can directly parse the .sql file and extract the relevant lines? I don't think there is an easy solution with `grep` and friends unfortunately, as mysqldump generates `INSERT` statements that insert many values per line.

Comment: Well, the way you do it seems to me to be the best way possible. Of course if you need to do it very often, it would be good to put some kind of (php) interface over it in order to make it more user-friendly. It will cost some time to develop, but you'll win it back each time you use it...

Comment: maybe with a good text editor, you could run some regexps to select or strip out the sql statements.

Comment: mysqldump is just that, a no-frills dump. You're doing it right by using a temp table to extract from the dump, but like @Bartdude said, scripting it would be the way to go. You'd just end up beating your head against wall trying to regex an SQL dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this just ended up being to import the whole file, extract the data I needed and drop the database again.